# Cannot kill VLC.exe using taskkill with os.system

Tags: python, cmd, vlc, os.system, taskkill

I have a very strange and perplexing issue here. I am attempting to automate the opening and closing of .wmv files with VLC Media Player. The code I used at first to open the file, works great:

```
# set directory    
os.chdir("Path/to/folder/containing/wmvfiles")    
# start the given file name
os.startfile("ExampleFileName.wmv")
```

Then I would use the following code to close this video when I was ready for it to be done playing

```
os.system("taskkill /im vlc.exe")
```

This worked great! However......I need it to open fullscreen. Sooo, I replaced my initial code to start the video with this:

```
 os.system
 ('""C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\\vlc.exe" -f "c:\videoFiles\\videoName.wmv""')
```

That worked great! It opens in full screen and all is well. However.....taskkill does not close the process. To be as specific as possible, this code doesn't close it, the VLC program will just stay open:

```
# open the file in full screen    
os.system
 ('""C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\\vlc.exe" -f "c:\videoFiles\\videoName.wmv""')
# close the file
os.system("taskkill /im vlc.exe")
```

Weird huh? It gets even worse. When I open the file this way:

```
os.system
 ('""C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\\vlc.exe" -f "c:\videoFiles\\videoName.wmv")
```

Then I go to the command prompt and type in

```
taskkill /im vlc.exe
```

It closes. I have absolutely no idea why the following:

```
os.system("taskkill /im vlc.exe")
```

Only works when I start my file the first way (os.startfile) and when I run the command directly from the command prompt. This may be a confusing question, but it is a very confusing problem, any help or input would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably only a copy and paste error, but the quotation looks strange: An opening single quotation mark without the corresponding closing one, followed by two double quotation marks, ... Please make sure that you post the code that you have tried, or is this already the error?  Also a closing bracket is missing in your second `os.system("taskkill /im vlc.exe"` line.

Comment: @maji fixed that, I just made typos while writing this up.

Comment: Are you sure that vlc is really running when you try to taskkill it?

Comment: @maji 100% I checked task manager and it is running. Plus I can use taskkill within the command prompt and it works as it should

Comment: My question was not clear: What happens if you add a `time.sleep(5)` between starting and taskkilling vlc? You need `import time` for this to work.

Comment: @maji I have been doing that, it shows up in task manager, clearly running, and still doesn't kill the process.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure. However, I wouldn't use `os`, I would use `subprocess`.

Something like:

```
import shlex, subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("cmd of some sort"))
#
# More code
#
p.terminate()
```

Comment: This makes me wonder if I could just terminate the process I started, that might work

Comment: The `subprocess` module was created to replace the usage of `os.system`. You will find more flexibility with it.

Answer (score 1):

> To quit vlc by itself after playing the video, use **`vlc://quit`** :

```python
import subprocess
vlc_path =r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe'
open_mp4 =r'C:\\video\\Lean On Me _ Playing For Change.mp4'
vlc_full =r'-f'
vlc_quit =r'vlc://quit'
subprocess.call([vlc_path]+[open_mp4]+[vlc_full]+[vlc_quit])
```